# Is there a way to snap geometry?

Tags: modeling, snapping

I am trying to model a protection fence, but there might be an easier way. I want to snap to the other geometry instead of adding vertices and doing it by hand. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create two objects, `top` (the rail you want to snap to), and `bar` (highlighted on the screenshot), in which assign the top 4 vertices to a vertex group `SNAP`, add an *Array *modifier to the `bar` object, and a *Shrinkwrap* modifier in *Project* mode, Z axis, with the target `top` and vertex group `SNAP`:

[image]

[image]